# s3 - how to get fast line count of file? wc -l is too slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3, aws-cli

Does anyone have a quick way of getting the line count of a file hosted in S3? Preferably using the CLI, s3api but I am open to python/boto as well.
Note: solution must run non-interactively, ie in an overnight batch.

Right no i am doing this, it works but takes around 10 minutes for a 20GB file:

```
 aws cp s3://foo/bar - | wc -l
```

Comment: Your command-line operation copies the entire file contents to the local machine to perform the `wc`. If you're going to be doing anything to the file _other_ than counting its lines, then you'll probably benefit paying that price once, and copying it locally. If all you care about is the number of lines, you may find it more useful to simply estimate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's two methods that might work for you...

Amazon S3 has a new feature called [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html) that allows you to query files stored on S3.

You can perform a count of the number of records (lines) in a file and it can even work on GZIP files. Results may vary depending upon your file format.

[image: S3 Select]

**Amazon Athena** is also a similar option that might be suitable. It can query files stored in Amazon S3.

Comment: Amazon Athena [has an SDK](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html) or can be [called from the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/). There is apparently an S3 Select SDK for Java and Python but I'm unable to locate it.

Comment: One limitation of the S3 Select is that it only works on CSV or JSON files, not arbitrary "lines". Re the SDK, it does take a short while for new APIs to be released.

Comment: this is not working for the file of more than 128MB.

Comment: @HrushikeshPatel What do you mean by "not working"? What is the error message you receive?

Comment: AWS saying "The maximum input file size of 128 MB is exceeded. This file is 397.6 MB. To work with larger files, use the API."

Comment: @HrushikeshPatel did you find any solution? using awssdk or cli?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Amazon S3 is having the SELECT feature, also keep an eye on the cost while executing any query from SELECT tab..
For example, here is the price @Jun2018 (This may varies) 
S3 Select pricing is based on the size of the input, the output, and the data transferred.
Each query will cost 0.002 USD per GB scanned, plus 0.0007 USD per GB returned.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using python/boto3.
Define bucket_name and prefix:

```
colsep = ','
s3          = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = 'my-data-test'
s3_key = 'in/file.parquet'
```

Note that S3 SELECT can access only one file at a time.

Now you can open S3 SELECT cursor:

```
sql_stmt    = """SELECT count(*) FROM s3object S"""  
req_fact =s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket  = bucket_name,
    Key     = s3_key,
    ExpressionType  = 'SQL',
    Expression      = sql_stmt,
    InputSerialization={'Parquet': {}},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {
                'RecordDelimiter': os.linesep,
                'FieldDelimiter': colsep}},
    
)
```

Now iterate thourgh returned records:

```
for event in req_fact['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        rr=event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        for i, rec in enumerate(rr.split(linesep)):
            if rec:
                row=rec.split(colsep)
                if row:
                    print('File line count:', row[0])
```

If you want to count records in all parquet files in a given S3 directory, check out this python/boto3 script: [S3-parquet-files-row-counter](https://github.com/pydemo/S3-parquet-files-row-counter)

Answer (score 1):

This answer here helped me to achieve faster results for all parquet files in a directory - https://donghao.org/2021/12/17/get-the-number-of-rows-for-a-parquet-file/

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
table = pq.read_table("my.parquet", columns=[])
print(table.num_rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following aws cli s3-select query helped get number of lines in a csv file stored in s3

```
aws s3api select-object-content \
--bucket <s3-bucket-name> \
--key <s3-key> \
--expression "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM s3object" \
--expression-type 'SQL' \
--input-serialization '{"CSV": {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}}' \
--output-serialization '{"CSV": {"FieldDelimiter": ":"}}' /dev/stdout
```

output

```
53261928
```